# Codeblock intallation repository

Tags: code-blocks

I have download codeblocks from Ubuntu software store but it is not working properly and giving error

> Can't find compiler executable in your configured search path's (for Intel C/C++ Compiler)

I have tried to fix it through `Setting -> Compiler -> Toolchain-executable` and `auto detect` path but its not working.

Comment: Can you check whether `g++` is updated? Try installing it, and `apt` will tell you. `sudo apt-get -s install g++`

Answer (score 0):

Run these first (in case `g++` is not updated)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Then,

1. Start Code::Blocks.
2. Select `Settings -> Compiler -> Toolchain-executable`.
3. Select the `[…]` button. Navigate to `/usr/bin`. The *C compiler* should be `gcc`, the *C++ compiler* should be `g++` and the *Linker for dynamic libs* should be `g++`.
4. Select `OK` to close the dialog box.

This worked for me. Hope this helps.

Comment: *in case g++ is not updated* --> is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//askubuntu.com/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.